# install taichi package on python

Tags: python, quick-install-package

I tried to run a script with python, it has taichi package downloaded from GitHub.

I have little knowledge of how python packages are installed, now I got error in command prompt like
"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'taichi'"

I just installed package downloaded from GitHub: https://pypi.org/project/taichi/#files

Hope someone can teach what should I do to run my script contains taichi package~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it our that this Taichi package needs 64 bits python, it also needs LLMV file downloaded. Besides, there should be virtual studio installed in the local computer.
Then this Taichi package can be installed just by using "pip install taichi" in command.

Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

To install packages in python you just run the command `pip install  (name of package)` in the command prompt so in your case that would be `pip install taichi`

Comment: Not OP but this does not seem to work for this specific module. Try it out and see if yours install mine says the module does not exist.

Comment: The [link](https://pypi.org/project/taichi/#files) you provided says to run that command

Comment: Again, not the OP. But yeah I tested that as well and it did not work. Wondering if maybe the module is having issues.

Comment: Yes it works , you can try `pip3 install taichi` or `python -m pip install taichi`

Comment: I cannot put a screenshot but definetly not working and I copied it from the website and what you put.

Comment: What does it say when you do `pip install taichi`

Comment: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement taichi (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for taichi

Comment: What about pip3 ?

Comment: Same error, and I know my environment is set up correctly because I develop on it on a daily basis. You said your install works right?

Comment: Yes , mine does . Maybe check your spelling or download the whl file and install that instead

Answer (score 0):

## How to install virtualenv:

#### Install **pip** first

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

#### Then install **virtualenv** using pip3

```
sudo pip3 install virtualenv
```

#### Now create a virtual environment

```
virtualenv venv
```

#### Active your virtual environment:

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

#### Now install your package for python

```
 pip3 install taichi
```

Comment: Thanks! I have followed your procedures successfully until creating virtual environment, a few python interface popped up, then disappeared, then I continue to activate in command line. Error appeared: 'source' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. Can you tell what I missed to do?

Comment: go to folder venv and run . bin/activate

Comment: I went to folder venv, but it told me: '.bin' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.  And I type "dir", there is no .bin file indeed, there were .gitignore, Lib, pyvenv.cfg, Scripts

Answer (score 0):

I alse encountered this problem,I confirmed that I have already successfully installed taichi whereas it still showed "no module named taichi" .And here is my solution:try`import sys`and`sys.path` to check whether the file of the packages is contained in python's search range.

For example,after I input`sys.path` in python ,it shows `['e:\\', 'd:\\anaconda2022\\python39.zip', 'd:\\anaconda2022\\DLLs', 'd:\\anaconda2022\\lib', 'd:\\anaconda2022', '', 'd:\\anaconda2022\\lib\\site-packages', 'd:\\anaconda2022\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'd:\\anaconda2022\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'd:\\anaconda2022\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']`

I am using anaconda as the python interpreter in vscode ,so the packages of taichi is installed in `d:\\anaconda2022\\lib\\site-packages`,and I can import it successfully . But previously my sys.path are incorrectly setted to `E:\\Python` but not `D:\\anaconda2022`. Python cannot find the packages of taichi from the wrong sys.path.

Check the sys.path in python may help.If it is the one which cause the problem , there are many ways to edit sys.path .I solved it by uninstalling the python for I installed python and anaconda at the same time (- -).