# install taichi package on windows with command promp

Tags: python

I am recently working on installing taichi package of python. I got the file for install taichi from this link:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yuanming-hu/taichi/legacy/install.py
But it gave me warning that the taichi file cannot be found, I do not know what else should I get.
This is their GitHub website: https://pypi.org/project/taichi/#files
and their documentation: https://readthedocs.org/projects/taichi/downloads/pdf/latest/
BTW, I have installed virtual environment as well, but I did not find .bin file.
Thanks so much!

Comment: Have you tried using pip? `pip3 install taichi`

Comment: _But it gave me warning that the taichi file cannot be found_ Please provide the entire warning message. _This is their GitHub website: https://pypi.org/project/taichi/#files_ Did you mean to link something else? _I have installed virtual environment as well_ Which tool are you using for those?

Comment: I asked questions in this thread before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62559167/install-taichi-package-on-python/62559446?noredirect=1#comment110725271_62559446. So I followed the instruction, but failed until activate step, so I tried taichi file on documentation. The virtual environment is needed according to the developer said in GitHub, I remember I saw it somewhere.

Comment: The full warning statement is:Executing command: git clone https://github.com/yuanming-hu/taichi.git --branch legacy
'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "install.py.txt", line 235, in <module>
    installer.run()
  File "install.py.txt", line 204, in run
    self.detect_or_setup_repo()
  File "install.py.txt", line 129, in detect_or_setup_repo
    os.chdir('taichi')
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'taichi'